# How to fix "TypeError: StreamingClient.add_rules() missing 1 required positional argument: 'add'"

Tags: python, tweepy

I'm trying to use tweepy to stream tweets and print the tweet body. When I run my code I get the following error:

```
TypeError: StreamingClient.add_rules() missing 1 required positional argument: 'add'
```

I've been reading the documentation and as far as I can tell I'm using the right syntax. The tweepy documentation uses this as an example of adding rules:

```
streaming_client.add_rules(tweepy.StreamRule("Tweepy"))
streaming_client.filter()
```

My code is as follows:

```
from multiprocessing.connection import Listener
import tweepy
from dotenv import load_dotenv
import os

load_dotenv()

# twitter api consumer key, consumer secret, access token, access secret.
btoken=os.getenv('btoken')

streamingClient = tweepy.StreamingClient(f"{btoken}")

class client(tweepy.StreamingClient):
    
    def on_data(self, data):
        print(data.text)
        return(True)

    def on_error(self, status):
        print(status)
        # Stops stream if rate limit is reached (status code 420)
        if status == 420:
            return False
        if status == 401:
            print("Authentication Error")
            return False

# Placeholder tracking keyword
trackKey = "walmart"
    
rule = tweepy.StreamRule((f"{trackKey} lang:en -is:retweet place_country:US"))

client.add_rules(rule)

client.filter
```

I'm using tweepy v4.10.1
Any help would be greatly appreciated and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is because, after declaring the class `client`, you hadn't created an object of this class, but attempted to call the method (inherited by this class from the class `tweepy.StreamingClient`) directly.
Normally class methods receive at least one argument: the object of the class, which is usually called `self`. This argument is usually passed automatically if the method is called like this `objectName.method()`. In this example, `objectName` is passed to the method `method()` as an argument `self`. But since you call this method not from an object of the class, but from the class itself, no first argument `self` is passed automatically. So the method believes that `rule` is that object of the class `tweepy.StreamingClient` (but hadn't had enough time yet to verify that and trigger a separate error) and complains about not receiving the second argument `add`.